# What's the maximum number of slots in the Adventure Pouch?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

My Adventure Pouch is full and I want to carry more items. I have expanded it as much as I think I can, but want to know if I can expand it further. What's the maximum number of slots in the Adventure Pouch? Please don't tell me *how* to expand further without using spoiler tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Adventure Pouch can hold a maximum of eight items. You start out with four slots and acquire four more during gameplay and that's it. You can't get more. You will have to choose what you want or need the most to carry around with you at a particular time and juggle with your belongings at the Item Check.

Where to get the four extra slots:

> Three of them can be bought at Beedle's Air Shop for 300, 600 and 1200 Rupees respectively. The other one is found in a Goddess Chest on the side of the Lumpy Pumpkin after activating the first Goddess Cube that Gorko the Goron points out.

Comment: Aw, man, really? I have all eight and was hoping there would be more somwhow! :-(